# Facebook Messenger consumes a lot of battery even if no messages are sent/received

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, battery, battery-life, motorola-moto-g2, facebook-messenger

I recently installed Facebook Messenger and it seems to be consuming a lot of battery, even if no messages are sent/received in a day.

Below is the battery usage for reference. As you can see Messenger used 12% of battery even though I did not use it the entire day, exceeding even the screen usage.

Is there a way to fix this? Uninstalling the app is my last option as sometimes I do want to send/receive messages on it.

[image]

Comment: You may use Faceebook Lite.

Comment: @alb3rtano0012: Facebook Lite is alternative for Facebook app, right? Or am I missing something here.

Comment: It's a lightweight alternative, an official app, and includes messaging too.

Comment: I see two ways: You either hibernate the apps or kill their wakelocks which means you won't receive notifications from them at all as long as they are not in focus on screen. Use Greenify for them. Else, use an approach where they would be killed when in background but would also be pinged to sync momentarily so you can at least receive notifications at particular intervals. This one can be done using DS Battery Saver or perhaps with Tasker too.

Comment: @alb3rtano0012: Went with Facebook Lite. Looks really ugly. But does the job.

Answer (score 2):

Both the Facebook and Facebook Messenger apps are notorious for excessive battery use. Seriously, social media is nowhere near important enough to warrant killing your phone battery. One way to help is to make sure that location reporting is turned off for both apps. You should actually go through all of the settings for both apps and disable every single thing you definitely don't need. All of the battery-sucking features are enabled by default.

Of course, the best thing to do is kick Facebook's apps to the curb and just access it through the mobile browser... but that's just my opinion,

Comment: `social media is nowhere near important enough to warrant killing your phone battery. ` -- You hit the nail right on its head. made me reconsider uninstalling the Messenger app

Answer (score 1):

Here are my **opinions.**

Firstly there is an application called "[WatchDog Task Manager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.zomut.watchdoglite)". You can install this application (or use the free version) and configure it so it kills processes exceeding certain thresholds. This can be set for the parameter of CPU or battery usage. This is primarily for CPU.

Another application you could configure is "[SnapDragon BatteryGuru](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.xiam.snapdragon.app)". Now this is highly opinion based, but I used this on my Samsung, HTC One M7 and M8 and noticed improved battery life. This application monitors your daily habits for battery and places certain application rules for when it syncs. This could assist in restricting FB (or even Messenger) from hogging battery.

You could also go to the extent of installing "[Memory Booster](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=imoblife.memorybooster.full)" which has several additional add-ins such as task killers and battery saving technics. I would not really believe this suitable, but it is a worthy mention.

Of course there are many other applications that you could look into that apparently help boost your battery life. The key to boosting battery life is minimising applications that actively have "wakelocks". More on wakelocks can be read here: [What are wakelocks](http://www.phonearena.com/news/What-are-wakelocks-how-they-affect-the-battery-life-of-your-Android-device-and-how-to-Greenify-them_id58739)?

Feel free to comment on this if I have missed anything or your disagree with this. If you believe this a sufficient and correct answer, please mark it so.

Comment: Not entirely relevant as an answer (hence the comment) but you could also apply the use of applications like AutoMateIT and Tasker to help end processes and save battery consumption.

Comment: From whatever I have read online, user's should not install any app which kills tasks or free memory. These things should be left to Android itself.

Comment: @Naveen This is correct, the act of doing so is not really required. However in your situation it doesn't seem tinge working and therefore may be beneficial. I advise you to to try Watchdog and tell me how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend [Greenify](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.oasisfeng.greenify&hl=en) to take care of these battery sucking applications.